# Postgres Left Outer Join not working with NULLS

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, left-join

I am trying to run the query below, but it is not returning the data as expected.   I noticed that if I remove the references to the LEFT JOINed tables in the SELECT portion, it works fine.    What am I doing wrong?

```
    SELECT m.ticker|| ' ' ||
           CASE
             WHEN x.ticker IS NULL THEN 'N'
             ELSE 'Y'
           END|| ' ' ||
           CASE
             WHEN s.ticker IS NULL THEN 'N'
             ELSE 'Y'
           END|| ' ' ||
           l.current_recommendation|| ' ' 
    ||TO_CHAR(l.recommendation_date,'MM/DD/YYYY')|| ' ' ||
           z.current_recommendation|| ' ' 
    ||TO_CHAR(z.date_recommended,'MM/DD/YYYY')
    FROM master_table m
    JOIN zrec_investars_recommendation l USING(ticker)
    JOIN all_recommendation_1 z USING(ticker)
    LEFT JOIN zer_ticker_data x ON x.ticker = m.ticker
    LEFT JOIN scr_tickers s ON x.ticker = s.ticker
    WHERE m.ticker = 'KEGX'
    ORDER BY CASE
      WHEN x.ticker IS NULL THEN 'N'
      ELSE 'Y'
   END DESC;
```

This however, works just fine:

```
   SELECT *
    FROM master_table m
    JOIN zrec_investars_recommendation l USING(ticker)
    JOIN all_recommendation_1 z USING(ticker)
    LEFT JOIN zer_ticker_data x ON x.ticker = m.ticker
    LEFT JOIN scr_tickers s ON x.ticker = s.ticker
    WHERE m.ticker = 'KEGX'
    ORDER BY CASE
      WHEN x.ticker IS NULL THEN 'N'
      ELSE 'Y'
    END DESC;
```

Why can't I perform the NULL tests in the SELECT portion?   Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean with "*it is not returning the data as expected*"? What does it return and what do you expect?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the concatenation is easier done with `concat_ws(' ', ...)`

Comment: See that I have criteria for a ticker, KEXG.   The top query does not return anything.   But, if I remove the CASE statements, as in the second query,  then it returns just fine.     What issue do those CASE statements cause?   Can I not do a NULL test on those values?

Comment: Are you saying you get a different number of **rows** depending on what you put into the SELECT list? That sounds very strange. The CASE _expressions_ do look fine to me though. Is it possible that any of the columns from `zrec_investars_recommendation` or `all_recommendation_1` might be NULL?

Comment: One of your columns is returning a NULL. When you concatenate a NULL into a string what you get out is a NULL. You are going to need to wrap every column you are concatenating in a `COALESCE(theColumn, '')` to insure that your NULL values don't nuke your concatenated string.

Comment: Well, the TICKER is the primary key in zrec_investars_recommendation and  all_recommendation_1.   So, I'm a bit lost right now.

Comment: Ticker might be the primary key, but what about `current_recommendation` or `date_recommended` or the other columns **not** `ticker`?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this has nothing to do with the CASE expressions, but some of the other columns might be null. And `something||NULL` returns `NULL` so the whole expression yields null.

You can easily verify this by running `select m.ticker, <your expression here> from ...`. Then you will see, that the rows returned are the same.

You can use `concat_ws()` instead, which treats `NULL` like an empty string. Plus it makes the whole thing easier to read:

```
SELECT concat_ws(' ', m.ticker,
                      CASE
                        WHEN x.ticker IS NULL THEN 'N'
                        ELSE 'Y'
                      END,
                      CASE
                        WHEN s.ticker IS NULL THEN 'N'
                        ELSE 'Y'
                      END,
                      l.current_recommendation, 
                      to_char(l.recommendation_date,'MM/DD/YYYY'), 
                      z.current_recommendation, 
                      to_char(z.date_recommended,'MM/DD/YYYY')
                 )
FROM ...
```

---

If you can accept `true` or `false` instead of `Y` and `N`, you can simplify the CASE expressions to: `(x.ticker IS NULL)::text`

Comment: This appears to work.  Not sure why it does not treat the NULL's the same way Oracle does, you can just refer to the field as an individual field, unless I am not understanding something.    But thanks!

Comment: @LandonStatis: because Oracle has a very strange handling of NULL values and empty strings. An empty string `''` is converted to a NULL value when you store it. However concatenating something with a NULL string, doesn't yield a NULL value. So `'x'||NULL` in Oracle yields `'x'` and `NULL` in every other database - including Postgres